# When filling a form, auto-insert values in a formatted text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, web-applications

I'm soliciting your help.
I made a form that I'd like to use at my job. As i have to make reports all day long, I though it'd be faster to have a form already ready to be copied/pasted in the software I use.

Here is a fiddle of what I've done so far : http://jsfiddle.net/5j0mfero/

When I fill "description" field, it does write everything in the "Preview" textbox but I don't succeed for other textboxes and checkboxes.

Things are that I'd like it to be pre-formatted this way :

```
Description :  //value of description's field  

Equipment : // value of equipment

Tests :  █ // value of checkbox
         █ // value of checkbox
         █ // value of checkbox
         █ // value of textbox "other"

Option : // values of "option" checkboxes comma separated

Terminal : // values of checkboxes + textbox "other"
```

Is it possible to do it with jquery or javascript ?
If yes, how should I do ?

Then afterwards I'd add a button in order to copy the preview box.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Hi @Ludo, I had a look at your jsfiddle and you should be able to. An approach could be as follows: apply a listener to **all** inputs you want to be shown in the preview. For text inputs this should be a keyup listener like you have done. For checkboxes you can use click events. You can implement this on the HTML or by targeting the elements and attaching listeners using JS. All these listeners should call **1** function that then gets their values from the DOM and produces the preview.

Comment: Thank you @M Mansour. I understood what you told me. Now that i checked about it, i'm facing another problem. Between the anchors <textarea></textarea>, if I pre-write with the template I want to use, how can i insert the values from the form at the right places? I want it in the text area because it has to be customizable. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I couldn't find <textarea>  in the jsfiddle so I am not 100% sure what you meant. Perhaps you can delete everything in the textarea and re-enter it every time the user makes changes to the form. Another, more complicated way, is to separate the values from the different parts of the form with a delimiter of some sort and use that to determine where/how to alter the preview based on the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [`fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/RaysOfTheSun/xpvt214o/857674/) :).

Also, click on the `Generate Report` button to get that formatted string you wanted instead because I couldn't think of way to have it dynamically generated every time any of the fields above get modified.

Comment: Hello C.RaysOfTheSun, Thank you very much for your fiddle! The tool works like a charm! For 2 days now i'm working with it and everything's fine. That's exactly what I was looking for. Awesome!!

Comment: That’s good to hear! Please don’t forget to mark this post as the answer if it has answered your question 